# Calculating mean annual runoff from monthly data in a netCDF file

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I working with a netCDF file with 113 years of global monthly runoff values (in mm):

```
<xarray.Dataset\>
Dimensions:  (X: 720, Y: 360, time: 1356)
Coordinates:

* X        (X) float64 -179.8 -179.2 -178.8 -178.2 ... 178.2 178.8 179.2 179.8

* Y        (Y) float64 -89.75 -89.25 -88.75 -88.25 ... 88.25 88.75 89.25 89.75

* time     (time) datetime64\[ns\] 1902-01-01 1902-02-01 ... 2014-12-01
  Data variables:
  Runoff   (time, Y, X) float32 nan nan nan nan nan ... nan nan nan nan nan
  Attributes: (12/13)
  title:                   GRUN
  version:                 GRUN 1.0
  meteorological_forcing:  GSWP3
  temporal_resolution:     monthly
  spatial_resolution:      0.5x0.5
  crs:                     WGS84
  ...                      ...
  EPSG:                    4326
  references:              Ghiggi et al.,2019. GRUN: An observation-based g...
  authors:                 Gionata Ghiggi; Lukas Gudmundsson
  contacts:                gionata.ghiggi@gmail.com; lukas.gudmundsson@env....
  institution:             Land-Climate Dynamics, Institute for Atmospheric...
  institution_id:          IAC ETHZ
```

Using xarray I'm trying to calculate the mean annual runoff value for each lat/long over the whole time period of the dataset using:

```
dsann = ds.resample(time='Y').sum('time').mean(dim=’time’)
```

The output has no time dimension:

```
<xarray.Dataset\>
Dimensions:  (X: 720, Y: 360)
Coordinates:

* X        (X) float64 -179.8 -179.2 -178.8 -178.2 ... 178.2 178.8 179.2 179.8
* Y        (Y) float64 -89.75 -89.25 -88.75 -88.25 ... 88.25 88.75 89.25 89.75
  Data variables:
  Runoff   (Y, X) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I'm feeling confident that part of this is correct.  When I run

```
 dsann = ds.resample(time='Y').sum('time')
```

I get:

```
<xarray.Dataset\>
Dimensions:  (time: 113, X: 720, Y: 360)
Coordinates:

* time     (time) datetime64\[ns\] 1902-12-31 1903-12-31 ... 2014-12-31
* X        (X) float64 -179.8 -179.2 -178.8 -178.2 ... 178.2 178.8 179.2 179.8
* Y        (Y) float64 -89.75 -89.25 -88.75 -88.25 ... 88.25 88.75 89.25 89.75
  Data variables:
  Runoff   (time, Y, X) float32 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I've also tried using groupby with similar results.

Thanks for any insights on this one.

Comment: ds.resample(time='Y').sum('time').mean(dim=’time’) is the mean of the 113 yearly sums of the dataset variables : it is normal it has no time dimensions. Can you describe more precisely your problem /question ?

Comment: Thanks Cyril - that's very reassuring.  I hadn't been able to add the output to a GIS but see how to now.